# Alternative for charts.googleapis.com for genrating QR code in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, qr-code

I have been using chats.googleapis.com for creating qr codes.
But now it is not working.

```
=image("https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=300x300&cht=qr&chl="&ENCODEURL(A2))
```

I have been using it in the above format for a while. I had no issues.
I guess something is wrong with the google api website.
So I am looking for an alternate solution for creating qr codes.

Answer (score 4):

```
=IMAGE("https://quickchart.io/qr?text="&ENCODEURL(A2))
```

I just found this one. Works fine.

Answer (score 4):

This service was deprecated in 2012; no one should be relying on it. It will be retired permanently next week. To help people realize when they're relying on it, Google turned the service off for an hour yesterday and two hours today. Tomorrow it'll be turned off for four hours, and the durations will increase until retirement.