# IMAGE function no longer returning result for google api generated QR code

Tags: google-sheets, google-api

I have a google sheet that returns a QR code based on some data entered into a cell on the sheet, using the google API

e.g.
`=IMAGE("https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=300x300&cht=qr&chl="&ENCODEURL(E2))`

However, I now just get a blank cell instead of the image.

The sheet has been in place and working without problem for around a year, but just seems to have stopped working since the new year. THe URL itself still opens up the QR code as expected, but no longer seems to work with the IMAGE function.

I have put a simplified version of the sheet here. The formula is in A2, which is where the image should be appearing

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iZAvZssEw6dwNuXK79wzWyT6lG7D0zGPnWWQV513I7Y/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Kindly check if this post answers your question: [Alternative for charts.googleapis.com for genrating QR code in google sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77757225)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Alternative for charts.googleapis.com for genrating QR code in google sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77757225/alternative-for-charts-googleapis-com-for-genrating-qr-code-in-google-sheets)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The chart.googleapis.com service was deprecated in 2012 and will be turned off completely over the next few days. Because Google has no way to reach users of this stateless service, it is draining the service intermittently (one hour last Wednesday, two hours yesterday, four hours today, eight hours tomorrow...) to alert users who are depending on this antiquated service.